# SelectAll from ngrx/entity doesn't select anything

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-entity

## Intro

I'm having some trouble getting my selector to work. My component doesn't update with books from the `FakeApiService` though I can see the call is made. So the actions and effects are working.

I believe the problem is related to my use of `@ngrx/Entity`. Specifically this

```
export const getBooksState = createFeatureSelector<DemoState>('demo');
```

and

```
export const { selectAll } = fromBook.adapter.getSelectors();
```

I've seen tutorials where they supply a selector function to `getSelectors()` but that shouldn't be necessary.

I'm hoping someone can spot where I go wrong, and if someone have some suggestions about the structure/setup I'm all ears :)

Here's my setup.

### Versions

- Angular: 6.0.0
- rxjs                              6.1.0
- typescript                        2.7.2
- webpack                           4.6.0
- @ngrx/effects 5.2.0
- @ngrx/entity 5.2.0
- @ngrx/router-store 5.2.0
- @ngrx/schematics 5.2.0
- @ngrx/store 5.2.0
- @ngrx/store-devtools 5.2.0

### ngRx

#### feature/store/actions/book.actions.ts

```
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Book } from '../../models/book';

export enum BookActionTypes {
  Load = '[Book] Load',
  LoadSuccess = '[Book] Load Success',
  LoadFail = '[Book] Load Fail'
}

export class LoadBooksAction {
  readonly type = BookActionTypes.Load;
}

export class LoadBooksSuccessAction implements Action {
  readonly type = BookActionTypes.LoadSuccess;
  constructor(public payload: Book[]) {}
}

export class LoadBooksFailAction {
  readonly type = BookActionTypes.LoadFail;
}

export type BookActions
  = LoadBooksAction
  | LoadBooksSuccessAction
  | LoadBooksFailAction;
```

#### feature/store/effects/book.effects.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Actions, Effect } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, map, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { FakeApiService } from '../../services/fake-api.service';
import { LoadBooksFailAction, LoadBooksSuccessAction, BookActionTypes } from '../actions/book.actions';

@Injectable()
export class BookEffects {
    constructor(
        private fakeService: FakeApiService,
        private actions$: Actions,
    ) {}

    @Effect()
    loadBooks$ = this.actions$
      .ofType(BookActionTypes.Load)
      .pipe(
        switchMap(() => this.fakeService.getBooks()),
        map(books => (new LoadBooksSuccessAction(books))),
        catchError(error => of(new LoadBooksFailAction()))
      );
}
```

#### feature/store/reducers/book.reducer.ts

```
import { EntityState, createEntityAdapter } from '@ngrx/entity';
import { Book } from '../../models/book';
import { BookActionTypes, BookActions } from './../actions/book.actions';

export interface BooksState extends EntityState<Book> {}

export const adapter = createEntityAdapter<Book>();

const initialState: BooksState = adapter.getInitialState();

export function reducer(state = initialState, action: BookActions ): BooksState {
  switch (action.type) {
    case BookActionTypes.LoadSuccess: {
      return adapter.addAll(action.payload, state);
    }

    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
}
```

#### feature/store/reducers/index.ts

```
import { ActionReducerMap, createFeatureSelector } from '@ngrx/store';
import * as fromOrder from './book.reducer';

export interface DemoState {
  demo: fromBook.BooksState;
}

export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<DemoState> = {
  demo: fromBook.reducer
};

export const getBooksState = createFeatureSelector<DemoState>('demo');
```

#### feature/store/selectors/book.selectors.ts

```
import * as fromBook from '../reducers/book.reducer';

export const {selectAll} = fromBook.adapter.getSelectors();
```

### Angular

#### feature/feature.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    StoreModule.forFeature('demo', reducer),
    EffectsModule.forFeature([BookEffects])
  ],
  providers: [FakeApiService],
  declarations: []
})
export class DemoModule { }
```

#### feature/components/book-view.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-book-view',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  template: `<book-list [books]="books$ | async"></book-list>`
})
export class BookViewComponent implements OnInit {
  books$: Observable<Book[]>;

  constructor(private store: Store<fromStore.BooksState>) {
    this.books$ = this.store.pipe(select(fromStore.selectAll));
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.store.dispatch(new bookActions.LoadBooksAction());
  }
}
```

Comment: put it in stackblitz

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Problem is with your Selector; You have to pass book/demo state into the getSelectors functions

```
import * as fromBook from '../reducers/book.reducer';

import { getBooksState } from '../reducers';

export const selectBookState = createSelector(
  getBooksState,
  state => state.demo
);

export const {
  selectAll
} = fromBook.adapter.getSelectors(selectBookState);
```

have a look at my repo and url

> https://github.com/rijine/itunes-album-angular/blob/master/src/app/album/store/selectors/albums.selector.ts

Comment: That looks like the demos/tutorials I've seen around the web. I don't understand the need for the state selector. I'm thinking it should be possible without it.

Comment: I was thinking same as you are thinking now. I had a same confusion, then I asked same kind of question in ngrx gitter too. Hope this will help you.

Comment: Its very easy to understand, you can put a break point in selector stateBookState and check the value of state.demo!